# Comparing two ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, loops, methods, arraylist, compare

I'm trying to write a method that takes 2 ArrayLists of doubles and returns all the values in set1 that aren't found in set2. These numbers should be returned in set3. Normally I would just use set.contains but I can only use set.get set.size and set.add. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

For example:

If set1 has the numbers 1,2,3,4,5

and set2 has the numbers 1,7,9,5,3

set3 should only contain 2,4,5

```
ArrayList<Double> setDiff(ArrayList<Double> set1, ArrayList<Double> set2){
    ArrayList<Double> set3 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for(int i = 0; i < set1.size(); i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < set2.size(); x++){
            if(set1.get(i) != set2.get(x)){
                set3.add(set1.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return set3;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Don't call them sets if they aren't sets :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, you are adding the number to `set3` based on the first failure. So, if the first element of `set2` does not matches the current element of `set1`, you are adding it to `set3`.

I suspect that this is your homework, given the restrictions in your toolkit. So, I'll just give you an idea of how to approach.

You can make use of a `boolean` variable, and toggle it (for e.g. set it to **`false`**), as soon as you find the current element in `set2`, and then break out of the `inner loop`.

So, your condition in the inner loop will change from: -

```
if(set1.get(i) != set2.get(x))
```

to: -

```
if(set1.get(i) == set2.get(x)) {
    // The current element in set1 is present in set2. 
    // toggle the boolean variable
    // break out of loop. As you no more want to check for further elements.
}
```

Then outside the `inner loop`, check the status of that `boolean` variable. And based on the status, you can add or not add the current item to `set3`. for e.g. If the boolean variable is `false`, that means you found the element in `set2`, so don't add it to `set3`, else add it.

You also need to reset the boolean variable at the start of the outer loop each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Apache commons [CollectionUtils.removeAll](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) method :this method returns a collection containing all the elements in c that are not in remove.

```
ArrayList commonList = CollectionUtils.removeAll(arrayList1, arrayList2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
static ArrayList<Double> setDiff(ArrayList<Double> set1, ArrayList<Double> set2) {
    ArrayList<Double> copy1 = (ArrayList<Double>) set1.clone();
    copy1.retainAll(set2);
    ArrayList<Double> copy2 = (ArrayList<Double>) set1.clone();
    copy2.removeAll(copy1);
    return copy2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList l1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0));
    ArrayList l2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1.0, 7.0, 9.0, 5.0, 3.0));
    System.out.println(setDiff(l1, l2));
}
```

prints

```
[2.0, 4.0]
```

Besides, I would suggest to change the method signature as

```
<T> List<T> listDiff(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
```